# Run arduino from terminal (snap)

Tags: command-line, snap, arduino

I've just installed arduino from Software Center but I've run into a few complications.

Port `/dev/ttyACM0` is not accessible so I can't upload anything.
I understand that this is a common problem, but none of the solutions seem to work for me. Except maybe running as `sudo` from the terminal which I haven't been able to figure out how to do.

```
Sketch uses 1,460 bytes (0%) of program storage space. Maximum is 253,952 bytes.  

Global variables use 9 bytes (0%) of dynamic memory, leaving 8,183 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 8,192 bytes.  
avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "/dev/ttyACM0": Permission denied   
ioctl("TIOCMGET"): Inappropriate ioctl for device  
ioctl("TIOCMGET"): Inappropriate ioctl for device  
avrdude: ser_send(): write error: Bad file descriptor  
avrdude: stk500_send(): failed to send command to serial port
```

I found a few "solutions" that don't seem to work for me.

1. run arduino as `sudo`:

   ```
   sudo: arduino: command not found
   ```

   It might work, but cant seem to get arduino to run from the terminal itself. I'm not sure but it might have something to do with it being "snap" and ignorance on my side on how to run these programs from terminal. I tried several paths (except the right one of course)
2. `$ sudo adduser <username> dialout`

   answer:

   ```
   The user `username' is already a member of `dialout'
   ```

   Of course  has been replaced by my username

   Also within arduino `/dev/ttyACM0` was black and available.
3. Also tried `sudo adduser <username> tty`

   The user was added, but no difference.
4. `$ sudo chmod a+rw /dev/ttyACM0`

   answer: already had the right read and write privileges.
5. `$ sudo udevadm trigger`

   tried this.. found it on Stack Overflow.

None really seemed to work though, so I keep trying to want to try to run it first from terminal as `sudo` but as I said I can't seem to figure out why arduino-mhall199. If this could work then it is enough for me, I don't use it often enough for that to be an issue.

Oh yeah of course. Ubuntu 17.10, sorry

Comment: I hope that `/dev/ttyACM*` is the serial device you are wanting... Paste in results of `ll /dev/ttyACM*`, and the command `id` please.  Also, to run from the command line, you actually use the command: `arduino-mhall119.arduino`, that might give you more output, and you can try as sudo (I don't know what will happen)

Comment: Take a look to https://askubuntu.com/questions/1025753/how-to-install-latest-arduino-ide . Snap is outdated, use `umake`.

Comment: @NOrbert: i just used ubuntu software to install. but i will uninstall and try umake too. i'll let you know.

Comment: @Norbert: worked like a charm!! thank you so much.

Comment: For your information we found the solution in my question [How to make Arduino (Snap) access serial port /dev/ttyUSB0 (or /dev/ttyACM0)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034024/how-to-make-arduino-snap-access-serial-port-dev-ttyusb0-or-dev-ttyacm0) . `umake` version of Arduino is of course newer, but some users may want to install it from Snap.