# How to install latest Arduino IDE?

Tags: software-installation, arduino

As we know Arduino has non-official Snap which can access serial ports only if [installed as *classic*](https://askubuntu.com/q/1034024/66509) (but not indicated in `snap find` output):

```
$ snap find arduino
Name                  Version  Developer  Notes  Summary
arduino-mhall119      1.8.5   mhall119   -      Arduino IDE
```

Arduino packages from repositories [are outdated](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&exact=1&searchon=names&keywords=arduino):

> Package arduino
>
> ```
> trusty (14.04LTS) (electronics): AVR development board IDE and built-in libraries [universe]
> 1:1.0.5+dfsg2-2: all
> xenial (16.04LTS) (electronics): AVR development board IDE and built-in libraries [universe]
> 2:1.0.5+dfsg2-4: all
> artful (electronics): AVR development board IDE and built-in libraries [universe]
> 2:1.0.5+dfsg2-4.1: all
> bionic (electronics): AVR development board IDE and built-in libraries [universe]
> 2:1.0.5+dfsg2-4.1: all
> ```

According to [official Arduino](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Software) site the latest version of Arduino IDE is 1.8.9.

One can download IDE from official site, extract and install it with `install.sh`. Then when newer version will be released repeat this action. But it looks difficult and not user-friendly.

How can I get latest Arduino IDE installed in user-friendly way?

Comment: related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/107619/how-do-i-install-the-arduino-ide

Comment: https://www.arduino.cc/en/guide/linux

Comment: Duplicate of [How to install the Arduino IDE?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107619/how-to-install-the-arduino-ide)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Arduino IDE is installable with [Ubuntu Make](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-make):

1. Install Ubuntu Make

   - for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS from official PPA [`ppa:lyzardking/ubuntu-make`](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-desktop/+archive/ubuntu/ubuntu-make?field.series_filter=):

     ```
     sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lyzardking/ubuntu-make
     sudo apt-get update
     sudo apt-get install ubuntu-make
     ```

     PPA is needed because of two fact: package for 16.04 LTS does not support installation of Arduino.

   > Note: umake from 18.04 Universe repo may fail installing arduino ide.
   >   If so, you will need to purge ubuntu-make and install from the PPA. 
   >   If this is the case you will also need to delete ~/.local/share/umake
   >   with `rm -rf ~/.local/share/umake`. See [this QA](https://askubuntu.com/questions/969080/error-the-checksum-of-android-studio-ide-doesnt-match-corrupted-download-abo) for more info.

   - for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and newer systems from [*universe*](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=ubuntu-make) repository:

     ```
     sudo apt-get update
     sudo apt-get install ubuntu-make
     ```
2. Install Arduino IDE with Ubuntu Make

   ```
   umake electronics arduino
   ```

   or for 18.04 (without PPA, may fail)

   ```
   umake ide arduino
   ```

   This will download Arduino IDE from official site and install it to *~/.local/share/umake/ide/arduino* and set corresponding shortcuts and file associations for it.

   You can repeat this command again to get newer version.

Note: do not forget to add your user to *dialout* group with `sudo usermod -a -G dialout $USER` .

Comment: Looks like the command is now `umake ide arduino`, at least on 18.04

Comment: Does this update it whenever anything else on my system updates?

Comment: No, you should run `umake ide arduino` manually each time. In Arduino case it is very useful as you can prevent the occurrence of new bugs (for example [this with internal Arduino Boards component](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/issues/7264#issuecomment-412343277)).

Comment: says `WARNING: Arduino is now in the electronics category, please refer it from this category from now on` on 19.10

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to install the latest Arduino IDE is to use [the arduino snap](https://snapcraft.io/arduino):

```
snap install arduino
```

Then add your user to the `dailout` group:

```
sudo usermod -a -G dialout $USER
```

After this, **reboot your device** and open Arduino IDE.

### A note about Python support

The Arduino IDE snap runs inside of a sandbox for security and stability reasons. This means it cannot access the Python libraries on your device. The snap bundles Python 3 and the `serial` library. If you need any other Python dependencies, you can install them inside of the sandbox using the `arduino.pip` command.

```
arduino.pip install <package-name>
```

*Note: do not use `sudo` for this command*

Comment: This sounds great, but Snap may not have access to removable media and data outside the home partition. So I prefer `umake`.

Comment: @N0rbert If you want to access removable media, just run `snap connect arduino:removable-media` or change the permissions of the app using "Settings".

Ideally, Arduino should just use [XDG Desktop Portal](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/xdg-desktop-portals/17331) so it can access any file the user chooses, but this is not yet supported for Java Swift apps.