# Uploading code to arduino gives me the error: "avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "/dev/ttyACM0": Permission denied"

Tags: 18.04, arduino

My OS is Ubuntu 18.04 and arduino was working until now.

Although there are a few solutions, none of them seems to work for me.

I followed [these instructions](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Linux#toc7) on the arduino website.

Then I tried [this on arduino Stack Exchange](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/21215/first-time-set-up-permission-denied-to-usb-port-ubuntu-14-04), which should work in cases where the first solution didn't. The answer says we should create a few rules on `/etc/udev/ruled.d/` path.

But none of them worked for me.

I also tested arduino in Windows 10 to see if it was a hardware problem, but it worked fine.

Does anyone have any other ideas on how to solve this issue?

**UPDATE:**

- My username, sergio, is part of both groups (tty and dialout);
- I logged out and back in as arduino official tutorial explains;
- In Arduino IDE, the configurations are correct: Arduino UNO and ttyACM0
- This is the output of `ll /dev/ttyACM0` after running the tutorial commands:

  ```
  crw-rw-rw- 1 root dialout 166, 0 Jul 15 05:41 /dev/ttyACM0
  ```

**UPDATE 2:**

I've created a script to solve this:
https://github.com/sergiomafra/iniarduino

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install latest Arduino IDE?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1025753/how-to-install-latest-arduino-ide) Did you forgot to logout and login again after running `usermod`?

Comment: Nope. First I tried to log out and in. Then I tried to restart my notebook. Nothing seems to work...

Comment: crw-rw-rw- 1 root dialout 166, 0 Jul 15 05:41 /dev/ttyACM0
Login: sergio            Name: Sérgio Mafra
Directory: /home/sergio              Shell: /bin/bash
On since Sun Jul 15 08:26 (-03) on :0 from :0 (messages off)
No mail.
No Plan.

Comment: dialout:x:20:sergio. When I tried to run the second command, bash returned to me No such file or directory

Comment: @Wiking first No such file or directory and second returns nothing. I installed arduino IDE from Ubuntu Software Center. I don't know if it tells something.

Comment: @Wiking oh, no problem. I saw it and fixed when I typed on terminal. The thing is that I don't have that file / folder on my home folder..

Comment: @N0rbert I don't think that this question should be closed as a duplicate of [How to install latest Arduino IDE?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1025753/how-to-install-latest-arduino-ide) because the accepted answer to this question is more specific to the question that was asked.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

I had a similar issue when I tried to upload a sketch to Arduino. The issue was connected to the lack of permissions to read/write to the serial port. I was able to fix by using the following command:

To confirm the port exists enter the following from the root directory.

```
ls /dev/ttyACM0
```

To set read/write permissions, enter the following

```
sudo chmod a+rw /dev/ttyACM0
```

Comment: Didn't work for me

Comment: This works for me, but this setting is not permanent for me. I have to this almost every time I upload a sketch

Comment: Or you can add the current user to the group `dialog`.

Comment: thanks @adrian! this worked;

Answer (score 14):

Reinstall your arduino installed from Ubuntu software center:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall arduino
```

Reinstalling is necessary since your `which avrdude` command according to your comment returns nothing, but should be `/usr/bin/avrdude`. Check again:

```
which avrdude
```

Run your Arduino IDE after  reinstalling and close it.

Check your arduino configuration. Open `/home/sergio/.arduino/preferences.txt` file and check there `serial.port` option. Try to change it to `/dev/ttyACM0`. Open that file:

```
sudo nano /home/sergio/.arduino/preferences.txt
```

and apply corresponding changes, i.e. the option should look

```
serial.port=/dev/ttyACM0
```

Restart computer afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I uninstalled it from Ubuntu Software Center and installed the version from arduino website and it worked.

Answer (score 7):

Here's what worked for me:

- Uninstall the version from Apt, it doesn't work properly (`sudo apt uninstall arduino; sudo apt autoremove`)
- Install the version from the Arduino website
- `sudo apt install avrdude` since the one from the website doesn't include it
- `sudo usermod -a -G dialout $USER` since the one from the website doesn't do this automatically (the `dialout` group owns the device file; this adds the current user to that group)

And now everything's working again!

Comment: It may be necessary to log out and back in, or even restart for the `usermod` command to take effect.

Comment: I followed the instructions, except I didn't reinstall Arduino. I have just installed `avrdude` and so on. It worked for me on `Ubuntu 22.04` with `Arduino 1.8.19`.

Answer (score 6):

This worked to fix the 'unable to open serial port' problem (put your Ubuntu username in instead of `$USER`) after downloading Arduino from Ubuntu Software.

```
sudo usermod -a -G dialout $USER  
sudo chmod a+rw /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Comment: Only these 2 changes (add user to dialout group AND permission change) worked for me, but you may have to change the number in ttyUSB0 for your case.

Answer (score 3):

In combination with all the posts I read, this is what I did to solve that issue by following directions from this thread.

In a new terminal, I typed the following as shown below.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifRmx.png]

Please note that fourplus is my username.

Comment: Welcome to ask ubuntu. In the future you should post text instead of images wherever possible.

Comment: Didn't work for me

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, I tried installing from Ubuntu Store on 18.04 and try everysolution here. Nothing worked for me. So [I downloaded the latest](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Software)

I extracted and ran the following command to install it:
$ sudo ./install.sh

After installing, I ran the script that came with the latest version by running the following:

$ ./arduino-linux-setup.sh <user_name>

Once the script is complete, it show you a message of "Please Rebook you system". I didn't restart when I try the solutions here, may be this is something that next users should try.

**Important**: When you install the software following these steps you need to go to Ubuntu Software and Give Permission to "Access Usb Hardware directly".

Answer (score 1):

I see that the question is already accepted but none of the solutions did it for me so I've got a different solution. I installed the arduino IDE via the Ubuntu software installer. What you need to do is.

1. Go to arduino IDE in Ubuntu software store
2. click permissions
3. set Access usb hardware directly on on

Comment: I've that setting by default and I have the problem

Answer (score 1):

ha I'm a newbie and I made some mistakes)) Don't do it the way I do.

1. First of all, in my book there was a bad picture about the led
   connection scheme. I found new one and reconnected wires. Now they
   are connected correctly.
2. Then I connected arudino to the computer (it's important).
3. Then I executed the following commands:

   - ls -l /dev/ttyACM0
   - sudo usermod -a -G dialout [my_username]
   - sudo chmod a+rw /dev/ttyACM0

When I was looking for a board in menu of arduino programm (Tools -> Board) I did not find an 'Arduino/Genuino Uno' just there was an 'Arduino Uno' (I guess it's OK)

Answer (score 1):

For me mixture of above two answers worked:
First was I couldn't find avrdude, `which avrdude` this gave me nothing. So, I had to reinstall the arduino.

```
sudo apt install --reinstall arduino
```

This installed avrdude, and I could find it in `/usr/bin/avrdude`.
Next thing was to set read/write permission to the serial port:

```
sudo chmod a+rw /dev/ttyACM0
```

Then I could upload the sketch on to my arduino!

Answer (score 1):

For me any `chmod` and `udev` rule did not work.

Only forcing `avrdude` to run as root worked:

```
$ sudo chmod u+s  /opt/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avrdude
```

Answer (score 1):

The OP's update 2 of creating a script solves the issue just fine. Check it out on [GitHub](https://github.com/sergiomafra/iniarduino).

```
2048@machine:~/Downloads/iniarduino-master$ iniarduino
[sudo] password for vipulgupta2048: 
Arduino connected!
Checking if 2048 is part of dialout and tty groups
2048 added to dialout group
2048 added to tty group
Password required to change permissions of /dev/ttyACM0
Permissions to /dev/ttyACM0 changed to a+rw
Reloading UDEV Rules
UDEV Rules reloaded without the need to restart
All Done!
```

Answer (score -1):

I got a solution.

1. Find your port to which the Arduino is connected (e.g. mine was `/dev/ttyUSB0`). You may find it mentioned in the error message in Arduino IDE.
2. Open the terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).
3. In the terminal run:

   ```
   sudo chmod 777 /dev/ttyUSB0
   ```

   The above command sets the required permissions.

Comment: "chmod 777"-- https://www.maketecheasier.com/file-permissions-what-does-chmod-777-means/

Comment: Didn't work for me