# How to access a device with Arduino IDE Flatpak

Tags: 18.04, ide, arduino, flatpak

I've installed Arduino IDE (1.8.5) with Flatpak (Kubuntu 18.04).

Attached my Wemos D1 Mini to the USB port, but can't upload a sketch:

```
An error occurred while uploading the sketch
error: cannot access /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Seems a bit silly that an IDE for a device in Flatpak can't access a device out of the box.

How do I fix that?

> This question is about **Flatpak**.
>
> *What additional action is necessary to get the Flatpak version of Arduino IDE working with a device?*
>
> (IMHO Flatpak needs to provide additional info/help in some way,
>   installing with Ubuntu Make `umake` seems easier.)

Comment: what does ls -l /dev/ttyUSB0 tell us? you might need to be in the dialout group

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install latest Arduino IDE?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1025753/how-to-install-latest-arduino-ide) (you need to execute `sudo usermod -a -G dialout $USER`).

Comment: @Joshua. I'm already a member of the dialout group `members dialout` shows my username.

Comment: Thx. I got it working by installing the IDE with Ubuntu Make `umake ide arduino` and logout/login.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the app starts with flatpak and that by default blocks devices. See [Accessing Serial Ports with an Application Runs in Flatpak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41252334/accessing-serial-ports-with-an-application-runs-in-flatpak)
by adding `--device=all` you get it work, but see comments on link.

---

> Most likely that's because Flatpak is blocking access to the serial
> device.
>
> Unfortunately at the moment I don't think there is a way to give
> access specifically to the serial devices, so you'd need to give
> access to all:
>
> ```
> flatpak run --device=all com.xamarin.MonoDevelop
> ```
>
> What this does is essentially mount the host's `/dev` inside the
> sandbox, so the app has full access to it.