# Arduino and Ubuntu 18.10: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: java, arduino, 18.10

On freshly installed Ubuntu 18.10 Arduino installed from official repositories can't start with error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at processing.app.Preferences.save(Preferences.java:735)
    at processing.app.Preferences.init(Preferences.java:249)
    at processing.app.Base.main(Base.java:117)
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 0, end 3, length 2
    at java.base/java.lang.String.checkBoundsBeginEnd(String.java:3319)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1874)
    at processing.core.PApplet.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    ... 3 more
```

How can I debug this issue?

Comment: How did you installed Arduino IDE? Which version do you have installed?

Comment: I can confirm your issue with arduino from the repository. But version from umake works as expected.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install latest Arduino IDE?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1025753/how-to-install-latest-arduino-ide)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to get old Arduino 1.0.5 working - then you should install previous version of OpenJDK - 8 and set it as default:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre openjdk-8-jre-headless

sudo update-java-alternatives --set \
java-1.8.0-openjdk-$(dpkg --print-architecture)
```

Do not forget to add your user to *dialout* group with `sudo usermod -a -G dialout $USER`.

But I can recommend to get modern 1.8.7 with help of Ubuntu Make (see [this Q&A for details](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1025753/how-to-install-latest-arduino-ide)).