# arduino ide 1.8.9 on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, versions, arduino

Giving an error when running ./install.sh

Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit
IDE version 1.8.9

I checked the script file

```
RESOURCE_NAME=arduino-arduinoid
```

this is what it has for RESOURCE_NAME

```
jarvis@jarvis-GS63VR-6RF:~/arduino_ide/arduino-1.8.9$ ./install.sh
Adding desktop shortcut, menu item and file associations for Arduino IDE...touch: cannot touch ‘/home/jarvis/.local/share/icons/hicolor/.xdg-icon-resource-dummy’: No such file or directory
touch: cannot touch ‘/home/jarvis/.local/share/icons/hicolor/.xdg-icon-resource-dummy’: No such file or directory
touch: cannot touch ‘/home/jarvis/.local/share/icons/hicolor/.xdg-icon-resource-dummy’: No such file or directory
touch: cannot touch ‘/home/jarvis/.local/share/icons/hicolor/.xdg-icon-resource-dummy’: No such file or directory
touch: cannot touch ‘/home/jarvis/.local/share/icons/hicolor/.xdg-icon-resource-dummy’: No such file or directory
touch: cannot touch ‘/home/jarvis/.local/share/icons/hicolor/.xdg-icon-resource-dummy’: No such file or directory
touch: cannot touch ‘/home/jarvis/.local/share/icons/hicolor/.xdg-icon-resource-dummy’: No such file or directory
touch: cannot touch ‘/home/jarvis/.local/share/icons/hicolor/.xdg-icon-resource-dummy’: No such file or directory
touch: cannot touch ‘/home/jarvis/.local/share/icons/hicolor/.xdg-icon-resource-dummy’: No such file or directory
touch: cannot touch ‘/home/jarvis/.local/share/icons/hicolor/.xdg-icon-resource-dummy’: No such file or directory
touch: cannot touch ‘/home/jarvis/.local/share/icons/hicolor/.xdg-icon-resource-dummy’: No such file or directory
touch: cannot touch ‘/home/jarvis/.local/share/icons/hicolor/.xdg-icon-resource-dummy’: No such file or directory
touch: cannot touch ‘/home/jarvis/.local/share/icons/hicolor/.xdg-icon-resource-dummy’: No such file or directory
touch: cannot touch ‘/home/jarvis/.local/share/icons/hicolor/.xdg-icon-resource-dummy’: No such file or directory
touch: cannot touch ‘/home/jarvis/.local/share/icons/hicolor/.xdg-icon-resource-dummy’: No such file or directory
touch: cannot touch ‘/home/jarvis/.local/share/icons/hicolor/.xdg-icon-resource-dummy’: No such file or directory
touch: cannot touch ‘/home/jarvis/.local/share/icons/hicolor/.xdg-icon-resource-dummy’: No such file or directory
touch: cannot touch ‘/home/jarvis/.local/share/icons/hicolor/.xdg-icon-resource-dummy’: No such file or directory

rm: cannot remove ‘/usr/local/bin/arduino’: No such file or directory
Removing symlink failed. Hope that's OK. If not then rerun as root with sudo.

rm: cannot remove ‘/usr/local/bin/arduino’: No such file or directory
Removing symlink failed. Hope that's OK. If not then rerun as root with sudo.

ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/usr/local/bin/arduino’: Permission denied
Adding symlink failed. Hope that's OK. If not then rerun as root with sudo.
 done!
jarvis@jarvis-GS63VR-6RF:~/arduino_ide/arduino-1.8.9$ sudo ./install.sh
Adding desktop shortcut, menu item and file associations for Arduino IDE...
rm: cannot remove ‘/usr/local/bin/arduino’: No such file or directory
Removing symlink failed. Hope that's OK. If not then rerun as root with sudo.

rm: cannot remove ‘/usr/local/bin/arduino’: No such file or directory
Removing symlink failed. Hope that's OK. If not then rerun as root with sudo.

 done!
```

Help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Run the command with root privileges. There's also a "arduino-linux-setup.sh" script which you may want to run.
This should install Arduino perfectly. Now if you are not able to use desktop shortcut for opening Arduino IDE, you can use this command

```
sudo chmod 777 arduino-arduinoide.desktop
sudo chown YOUR_USERNAME_HERE arduino-arduinoide.desktop
```

This will make you the owner of the file, give you read and write permissions, and you will be able to open it then.

You can also open Arduino ide by using this command in the arduino folder.

```
./arduino
```

Comment: Probably you might want to see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1025753/how-to-install-latest-arduino-ide?rq=1