# Arduino IDE for (X)ubuntu 19.10

Tags: apt, arduino

I recently installed Ubuntu 19.10. on my digital slave.

From official repositories, there is no chance of an installation of Arduino IDE. Please confirm.

Comment: Please add the output from `apt-get update` and `apt-get install arduino`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install latest Arduino IDE?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1025753/how-to-install-latest-arduino-ide) and also check that you have *universe* pocket enable. If unsure then run `sudo add-apt-repository universe` and then proceed.

Answer (score 0):

I see it there:

https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/arduino

You might want to check your sources.list

Comment: Already tried this - no change seen.

Comment: Tried what @PascalKlein ? This answer only asserts that there is such a package. The only thing to "try" is "check your `sources.list`". Have you checked your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and does it have the correct repository configured? If you're not sure, please post the contents in your question