# HELP - Arduino install wrecked my Ubuntu desktop

Tags: ubuntu-mate, arduino

Earlier tonight I downloaded Arduino 1.8.12, the Linux 64-bit version from https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Software, for use with the Keyboardio Model 01 keyboard.

It downloaded to my Desktop/Downloads folder.  I then applied the commands described at: 
https://github.com/keyboardio/Kaleidoscope/wiki/Install-Arduino-support-on-Linux

This is what I did, from my user home directory shell prompt:

```
$ cd Desktop/Downloads
$ tar xvf arduino-1.8.12-linux64.tar.xz
(a long list of stuff opened and installed)

$ sudo mv arduino-1.8.12 /usr/local/arduino
$ cd /usr/local/arduino
$ sudo ./install.sh
```

Suddenly I noticed that most of the icons in my top panel were now missing. Then I noticed that my desktop icons were all generic icons. So I re-booted. Upon re-boot, I get a blank screen in both my monitors. For one or two quick flashes, I can see my usual interface behind the blank screen (ssh window, browser, etc).

Can anyone help me figure out WHAT JUST HAPPENED?!

This is on Ubuntu-MATE 16.04.  I had already successfully flashed the latest firmware onto my Keyboardio Model 01 the day before.

I am writing now from a separate drive in my desktop workstation where I have the old Ubuntu 14.04 installed. From here I can open the 16.04 drive and I see that in /usr/local/arduino that the arduino components appear to have been installed.

I can also see that a file named "Arduino IDE" is on my desktop, and that it's a "desktop configuration file," (application/x-desktop) but it will not open.

Right now I have no direct normal graphical access to my entire 16.04 system, which is very scary. This sort of thing hasn't happened to me in quite awhile.

The install.sh script that's in /usr/local/arduino is on pastebin here:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/WXbQMgQh3R/

Any tips or suggestions about what went wrong here greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:  AT THIS POINT I JUST NEED TO GET MY DESKTOP BACK.  I'm still getting a blank screen when I log into my ubuntu-MATE 16.04.  Also, on my login page, the background image is now gone, and the background is black. (I'll worry about Arduino later.)

Comment: FYI: Ubuntu MATE 16.04 LTS being a flavor of Ubuntu had only 3 years of supported life (http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/03/01/ubuntu-16-04-6-lts-released/) which ended 2019-April. Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Server (no desktop) or Desktop (Unity 7) have 5 years of supported life and are still supported. Refer release notes, or use `ubuntu-support-status` or your own system to confirm this is the case. I suggest you move to a supported release of Ubuntu-MATE for security reasons, unless you're off-line or are aware of risks.  https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/ubuntu-mate-16-04-lts-reaches-end-of-life/19425

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of this, I assumed MATE had the same support life as stock Ubuntu. But right now I cannot get to a terminal window on my Ubuntu-MATE 16.04.  I'll upgrade to MATE 18.04 as soon as I can, but right now I need to get my desktop back.  I am also doing my workplace work from home which may delay an upgrade to 18.04.  My guess is that my failed attempt to install Arduino has little to do with MATE end-of-life (I could be wrong) since everything else has been working fine on MATE.

Comment: You can check the `install.sh` script which caused the problem, maybe post the script here or at https://paste.ubuntu.com ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. See pastebin link in my post above.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install latest Arduino IDE?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1025753/how-to-install-latest-arduino-ide)