# arduino IDE import serial ImportError: No module named serial

Tags: tty, arduino

I **want to program my ESP32** as I did 100000000000 times before.
Now I want to try it on linux ubuntu :)
In preferences I put in the *.json link and installed the espressif board.
I think I chose the right board.
**Something is wrong with the serial port:**
When I click on board information it shows some serial number

```
BN: Unbekanntes Board
VID: 10C4
PID: EA60
SN: Laden Sie ir(...)
```

But when I want to upload it to the board it just shows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/.arduino15/packages/esp32/tools/esptool_py/3.0.0/esptool.py", line 38, in <module>
    import serial
ImportError: No module named serial
exit status 1
Fehler beim Kompilieren für das Board DOIT ESP32 DEVKIT V1.
```

I also did pip install pyserial
~$ python --version
Python 2.7.18

hmm there must also be something wrong?

```
~$ sudo ls -l /dev/ttyUSB0
crw-rw----+ 1 root dialout 188, 0 Sep  8 15:02 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

I can open Arduino IDE with sudo, which is with root i think.
And also with my account without sudo.
..
I have different workspaces i think
because i needed to install the board again, when I opened Arduino IDE with sudo
..
actually  I dont know what dialout is
maybe I did it by mistake when installing esp support-.-
..

I also tried to change the group and give all permission via chmod 777
but it doesnt work

```
/dev# ls -l ttyUSB0 
crwxrwxrwx+ 1 root root 188, 0 Sep  8 15:02 ttyUSB0
```

anyway after put esp32 out and in again ttyUSB0 chmod777 config is resetted ............................

```
ls -l ttyUSB0
crw-rw----+ 1 root dialout 188, 0 Sep  8 15:36 ttyUSB0
```

I also checked my esp32 board now on w10 and there is no problem.
Installation was done in 10 minutes (with a big break, making a banana shake xD)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install latest Arduino IDE?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1025753/how-to-install-latest-arduino-ide) ← You should not run Arduino IDE as root. Instead add your user to dialout group, install Arduino IDE using ubuntu-make and then install ESP32 tools as ordinary user.

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem and I tried below codes, and it worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install python-serial -y
```

or if you are using the python3 try:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-serial -y
```

Also use lower baudrate as you can see below:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for this answer, very helpful. I had first installed pyserial, which didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

The problem was that I have multiple python versions installed and serial was only available for python 3.

Check if serial is installled for python version 2:

```
ls /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/
```

If it doesn't appear, copy the library from python version 3:

```
sudo cp -r /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/serial/ /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is where I just found the solution, fellows! I installed pyserial in every way without results, but this one worked!

https://www.esp32.com/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=26670

1. Open a terminal;
2. Type in 'sudo apt install python-is-python3'

This package is about 500 Mega bytes big, but it did the trick I was expecting for months.

Comment: Could you put the steps in your answer? If the link breaks your answer won’t be useful any more.  Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, sir! I will proceed this way from now on!