# How to make Arduino (Snap) access serial port /dev/ttyUSB0 (or /dev/ttyACM0)?

Tags: permissions, 18.04, snap, serial-port, arduino

I have Ubuntu 18.04 LTS installed.

I installed Arduino IDE v1.8.5 as a snap with

```
snap install arduino-mhall119
```

I have added my user to dial-out group and rebooted:

```
sudo usermod -a -G dialout $USER

$ groups 
username adm dialout cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare
```

I connected my Arduino Nano to the laptop, it is detected on port */dev/ttyUSB0* (*ch341-uart*).

```
$ ls /dev/ttyUSB0 -al
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188, 0 авг 13 11:59 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

I tried to upload the simpliest *Blink* sketch and get the following errors in the terminal:

```
$ arduino-mhall119.arduino 


avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "/dev/ttyUSB0": Permission denied  
Problem uploading to board.  See http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#upload for suggestions.**
```

Also I have installed `arduino` 1.8.5 with umake - it can access serial port in usual way.

Note: we already have [similar question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1025633/66509) here, but the solution was to use [package from `umake`](https://askubuntu.com/a/1025755/66509), not fix for the Snap.

So my question is: How to make Arduino (Snap) access serial port /dev/ttyUSB0 (or /dev/ttyACM0)?

Update: connecting *serial-port* to the snap fails with the following message

```
$ snap connect arduino-mhall119:serial-port 
error: snap "core" has no "serial-port" interface slots
```

Current interfaces are:

```
$ snap interfaces | grep arduino
:home                            arduino-mhall119,gedit,organize-my-files,vlc
:network                         arduino-mhall119,gedit,organize-my-files,pulsemixer,vlc
:unity7                          arduino-mhall119,gedit,organize-my-files,vlc
:x11                             arduino-mhall119,organize-my-files,pulsemixer,vlc
-                                arduino-mhall119:serial-port
```

Changing permissions of serial port to 777 with `sudo chmod 777 /dev/ttyUSB0` does not help.

The following do not work too (because of syntax errors):

```
$ sudo snap connect arduino-mhall119:arduino
error: snap "arduino-mhall119" has no plug named "arduino"

$ snap connect arduino-mhall119:/dev/ttyUSB0
error: snap "arduino-mhall119" has no plug named "/dev/ttyUSB0"

$ snap connect arduino-mhall119
error: cannot resolve connection, plug snap name is empty
```

Information about YAML-manifest:

```
$ ls -l /snap/arduino-mhall119/current/meta/snap.yaml
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 353 июл 28 00:20 /snap/arduino-mhall119/current/meta/snap.yaml

$ cat /snap/arduino-mhall119/current/meta/snap.yaml |grep -A 12 slots

$ cat /snap/arduino-mhall119/current/meta/snap.yaml |grep -A 5 plug
    plugs:
    - x11
    - unity7
    - home
    - network
    - serial-port
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `arduino-mhall119` snap is outdated and should not be used anymore. **Use the [`arduino`](https://snapcraft.io/arduino) snap instead.**:

```
snap install arduino
```

Using that snap, the only thing you need to do is add your own user to the `dailout` group:

```
sudo usermod -a -G dialout $USER
```

After this, reboot your device and open Arduino IDE.

Answer (score 11):

### 2020 update

The `arduino-mhall119` snap is outdated and should not be used anymore. Use [the `arduino` snap](https://snapcraft.io/arduino) instead.

See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1240005/172367) for up to date info on how to get serial working with the `arduino` snap.

### Old instructions

**Install the snap in classic mode to allow access to ports**

```
$ snap install arduino-mhall119 --classic
```

It's that simple. You should now have access to your serial ports! Happy Hacking!

Note: info below are needed for old Arduino 1.6.10.

---

---

**Some interesting links that helped find the answer**

[Auto connected serial port interface](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/auto-connected-serial-port-interface/3014/8)

> Lundamar says:
>   Until the serial-port gadget/interface is improved to give access to all system serial devices you can get your snap working by simply installing it non-confined like so:

```
$ snap install tio --classic
```

> It’s better than nothing but it surely would be best to run it confined with allowed access to serial tty devices.

[Interfaces - `serial-port`](https://github.com/snapcore/snapd/wiki/Interfaces#serial-port)

[Interfaces reference](https://docs.snapcraft.io/reference/interfaces):

> `serial-port`
>   Can access serial ports. This is restricted because it provides privileged access to configure serial port hardware. Note that the slot is meant to be implemented by a **gadget snap** (this is not provided by the core snap).

[Gadget providing serial-port slot](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/gadget-providing-serial-port-slot/4063/4)

Comment: Made your answer more comprehensive, so you can remove all comments below the question. Thank you for all you help!

Comment: Thank you. I was having the same problem and your solution worked for me. I don't understand though. A few months back my Arduino IDE was working fine, I didn't change anything, and now I just wasted 3 hours, added permissions to the ttyUSB0 (which were there to begin with), I already belonged to the group dialout, rebooted multiple times and prayed over and over. And a simple '--classic' solved it. Seriously man, wtf! I read your answer multiple times, it is gibberish to me. I'd think installing the IDE from Ubuntu Software manager should have worked right out of the box (like it did before).

Comment: Well, now there isn't the esp32 in the Board Manager. It feels like it's 1996 all over again.

Comment: Never mind, I'm kinda brain dead already and forgot to add the esp32 URL to the Board Manager in Preferences... thanks again for your solution.

Comment: I am getting `Warning: flag --classic ignored for strictly confined snap arduino-mhall119` and doesn't fix it

Answer (score 1):

The solution of Joshua did not work for me anymore since I got the error:

`Warning: flag --classic ignored for strictly confined snap arduino-mhall119`

However, when using devmode instead it worked fine:

```
$ snap install arduino-mhall119 --devmode
```

Not sure if there are any further consequences with devmode though..